# How many colleagues went to Starbucks?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

You go to Starbucks with some colleagues, everybody gets a cappuccino. Every cappuccino contains only coffee and milk (at least some coffee and some milk) and no other ingredients, but everyone has a different ratio. If in your cappuccino there is 50% of the total milk used to make your and your colleagues cappuccinos, and the 25% of the total coffee used, how many colleagues did you go with?

Comment: Starbucks has different serving sizes, don't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $25$% of the total coffee and $50$% of the total milk:

> The total amount of coffee and milk would be four times your coffee added to twice your milk. This could be shown in the expression $4x+2(x-100)$, where $x$ is the percent of coffee that you have. The total amount must also be a multiple of $100$%, as there are a whole numbers of cappuccinos. In addition, the percentage of coffee must be between $0$ and $100$ exclusive, so the function now has a domain.

Using this, we find:

> If you graph the equation $y=4x+2(x-100)\{0<x<100\}$, the only time the line intersects a multiple of $100$ is at the point $(50,300)$. This means that your cappuccino must be half coffee and half milk.

So there are:

> **Two colleagues**, in addition to yourself. The total percentage is $300$%, so there are three cappuccinos. You have half and half, and your colleagues could, for example, have $70$% and $80$% coffee and $30$% and $20$% milk.